# GoogleCharts - How to display data in stacked form - ComboChart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I have a chart - I want to group values by month, and stack the numbers for each month by category.

This is the [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zRt-qqv-BArLV0jJGbaE-NxnOWE0YLbTfPNCOI4hPAk/edit#gid=0). The idea here is there is values that have dates, categories, and costs.

I'd like to display a stacked combo chart where the Y is month, the X is cost, but the bar displayed is stacked in sections by category.

Similar to something that looks like:

[image: example:]

[Here's my attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/jeag1gva/43/) -- I'm close, I just can't get the categories to show/stack.

Code from attempt:

```
var options = {
    title: "Cost By Month/Category",
    tooltip: {
        showColorCode: true
    },
    isStacked: true,
    yAxis: {
        format: 'MMMM'
    },
    bars: 'vertical',
    seriesType: 'bars'
};
```

Any help?

Comment: I'm afraid this will not work with the given structure of your SpreadSheet. You must use columns for each single category and store the costs in these columns. Like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lya8KhfoNCVWKPUF-4_T95v6ysCuj6gaKVQOquMvHjM/edit#gid=0

Comment: That is very helpful to know. Thanks so much!

Comment: But: of course the required structure of the spreadsheet may not be a good solution as well, especially when you want to add new categories without modifying the application which draws the data. You still have the option to leave the spreadsheet-structure as it is and create the DataTable on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

You have only one category and because of that it looks like normal combo chart if you have more than one category it will appear as stacked, for stacked chart `isStacked: true` will display combo chart into stacked chart.

Comment: I don't understand -- The column B in the spreadsheet, has more than one category. I would expect each category in the B column to have it's own place in the stack.